# ES6: クラスの中でプロパティを変更する方法

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6

下記のコードでプロパティの値は`5`に変わりません：

```
class TestClass{

  constructor(prop){
    this.prop = prop;
    TestClass.validateProp(prop); // 例えばpropは整数で、最小値は５でなければなりません
    console.log(this.prop)
  }

  static validateProp(prop){
    // 仮にこれは不正だとします
    this.prop = 5; // 最小値に設定
  }

}

let testInstance = new TestClass('不正値');
```

もしかして、ゲッター・セッターが必要かもしれません。インタネットで例の数は少なく、ゲッター・セッターの宣言で終わる事が多いです。[こちら](http://memolu.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/07/06/005006)の投稿を基にして、上記のコードにゲッターとセッターを追加しましたが、`prop`は`5`に成っていないままです。

```
class TestClass{

  constructor(prop){

    this.prop = prop;
    TestClass.validateProp(prop); // 例えば最小値は５でなければなりません
    console.log(this.prop)

  }

  set prop(newValue){
    this._prop = newValue;
  }

  get prop(){
    return this._prop;
  }

  static validateProp(prop){
    // 仮にこれは不正だとします
    this.prop = 5; // 最小値に設定
  }
}

let testInstance = new TestClass('不正値');
```

どうすればよろしいでしょうか。

（上記の例には、規定値が役に立ちますが、この質問の中心はクラスの中にプロパティを変更する事ですから、規定値を置いてください）

Comment: 最初の例で `validateProp` が static method になっているので、`TestClass.validateProp(prop);` を `this.constructor.validateProp(this);` として（インスタンスオブジェクトを渡す）、`static validateProp(obj){ if (obj.prop !== undefined) obj.prop = 5; }` とするとか。

Comment: @metropolis, 答えになります！答えてくださいまして、誠にありがとうございます。

Comment: @metropolis さん、時間が経ってしまいましたが、こちらのコメントを回答としてご投稿願えませんか？

Answer (score 2):

オブジェクト指向プログラミングをサポートしている言語は、どの言語でも、静的メソッドからインスタンスを参照できません。質問にある例だと、もっとも簡単な解決策は`validateProp`メソッドを非静的メソッドにする方法です：

```
class TestClass{

  constructor(prop){
    // ちなみに、パラメターを使ってからこれをバリデーションするのは変な書き方です
    this.prop = prop;
    this.validateProp(prop); 
  }

  validateProp(prop){
    // ...
    this.prop = 5;
  }
}
```

静的メソッドにこだわりがあれば：

```
class TestClass{

  constructor(prop) {
        // 動いていますが、無駄なコードが多い
        if (!TestClass.isPropertyValid(prop)) {
            prop = 5;
        }
        this.prop = prop;
  }

  static isPropertyValid(prop){
    return prop >= 5;
  }
}
```

この例の一番簡潔な書き方：

```
class TestClass{
  constructor(prop) {
        this.prop = prop >= 5 ? prop : 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getter, setter を使うなら、値を共有する優れた手段(private property)が標準に存在しない事が問題になります。

```js
'use strcit';
const TestClass = (() => {
  const wm = new WeakMap;

  return class TestClass {
    constructor (prop) {
      wm.set(this, Object.create(null));
      this.prop = prop;
    }
    get prop () {
      return wm.get(this).prop;
    }
    set prop (prop) {
      prop = Math.floor(prop);
      return wm.get(this).prop = prop < 5 ? 5 : prop;
    }
  }
})();

const test = new TestClass(2);
console.log(test.prop); // 5
```

Re: @Gurebu Bokofu